# Selecting 'k' elements out of a large 'N'-elements array such that the sum of their mutual difference is the least

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

For example, I have say `x1,x2..,xn.` I have to select `'k'` elements out of those n elements such that--let the selected elements be `y1,y2,y3,..yk`--the sum of `|y1-y2| + |y2-y3| + |y3-y1| + ...` will be the minimum.

In other words, the sum of the mutual differences among those `K` elements should be lesser than or equal to any other selection of `K` elements.

The elements `x1,x2..xn` are not sorted and may contain duplicates.

I have the most basic solution for this i.e., to sort the array--let the sorted array be z--and slide a window of k elements from `i = 0 to i = n-k-1` and as they're sorted the sum of mutual difference value takes a common form of :

```
(k-1)*z[0] + (k-3)*z[1] + (k-5)*z[2] + ........  -(k-1)*z[k-1].
```

Finding the minimum mutual difference gives me the answer.

Obtaining the minimum sum of mutual differences will suffice as the rest of the code takes only that as an input.

I need to optimize or find a better algorithm to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking to optimize further. I mentioned the most basic solution, see? Read it again, maybe?

Comment: Take a look at [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). You can use that after your O(n log n) sort.

Comment: This problem is from an ongoing contest. Asking help from others during the contest spoils the fun part according to me.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Not to mention that it would be against the rules for most such contests. And it's always helpful to provide a link with claims like that.

Comment: @Dukeling The link is https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/oct13/challenges/angry-children-2

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov [so] welcomes purely algorithmic questions. From all the algorithmic questions posted the past few months on [so], [programmers.se] and [cs.se] (which are the main candidates, along with maybe [codegolf.se], which is mainly about, well code golf), [so] has by far the most. (Though I would like [a dedicated place](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for them). And, in my opinion, algorithmic questions should stay away from code (just high-level and pseudo-code) - code is often difficult to read and understand, and it shouldn't be required to know some language to participate.